# Xna collision Prob

Tags: c#, xna

i have problem with doing game 2D

now till now i did:
create Player + map + Keyboard+ mouse
now i am doing the collision with the Player and the map

and i try that if the Player though One or more blocks with that code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    class UpdateCollision
    {
        Player myPlayer;
        Map myMap;

        public void Initialize(Player myPlayer, Map myMap)
        {
            this.myPlayer = myPlayer;
            this.myMap = myMap;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            // Use the Rectangle's built-in intersect function to 
            // determine if two objects are overlapping
            Rectangle Player;
            Rectangle Block;

            // Only create the rectangle once for the player
            Player = new Rectangle((int)myPlayer.Position.X,
            (int)myPlayer.Position.Y,
            myPlayer.Width,
            myPlayer.Height);

            // Do the collision between the player and the Block

            int i, j;

            // For each block in the game
            for (i = 0; i < myMap.Height / myMap.pictureSize; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < myMap.Width / myMap.pictureSize; j++)
                {
                    // If the block is Draw
                    if(myMap.Blocks[i, j].isAlive)
                    {
                        Block = new Rectangle((int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].X,
                                              (int)myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y,
                                                   myMap.pictureSize,
                                                   myMap.pictureSize);

                         // Determine if the two objects collided with each
                         // other
                        if (Player.Intersects(Block))
                         {
                            MessageBox.Show(myMap.Blocks[i, j].X+ ","+myMap.Blocks[i, j].Y);
                         }

                    }
                }
            }


        }

        public void Draw (SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {


        }
    }
```

and it never goes to message box even when it tough

image of the Meeting [image]

Comment: `MessageBox`? In an XNA game? What.

Comment: When you says it 'never goes to the message box', you're using a breakpoint, right? So simply check the coordinates of both objects to know why the `Intersect` is not firing. `Intersect` is a native method, so the problem is probably 100% on your side. And good grief remove that `Windows.Forms` DLL dependency! I've seen some strange things with XNA, but that.. that probably wins an award.

Comment: yes it true i use the messagebox to only show info i will remove it
but still it not working

Answer (score 2):

@ Pierre-Luc Pineault thank you
i played that

my mistake was the mistake in the Blocks class
i set it  the Y as X and the X as Y so all was upset now it worked

thank you